# Why am i getting an Finalizing a cursor that has not been deactivated or closed error in SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception, cursor

I'm a noob to android  and I'm getting a frustrating IllegalArgumentException.  the logcat says Finalizing a cursor that has not been deactivated or closed.  I've read all the related questions on stackoverflow and still can't figure out what's going on.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

The code that brings the error:

```
    public void add(){
    boolean didItWork = true;
    try {
        //String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
        //String hotness = sqlHotness.getText().toString();
        calculateaddentry();
        String coin = addcoinselection.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String quantity = sqlAddCoin.getText().toString();
        String ounces = entryounces;
        String value = denomination + newentryvalue;


        //PortfolioDatabase entry = new PortfolioDatabase(Portfolio.this);
        info.open();
        info.createEntry(coin, quantity, ounces, value);
        info.close();

        info.open();
        String data = info.getData();
        info.close();
        info.open();
        String ccoin = info.getCoin();
        info.close();
        info.open();
        String cqty = info.getQty();
        info.close();
        info.open();
        String counces = info.getOunces();
        info.close();
        info.open();
        String cvalue = info.getValue();
        info.close();

        currentcoin.setText(ccoin);
        currentqty.setText(cqty);
        currentounces.setText(counces);
        currentvalue.setText(cvalue);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        didItWork = false;
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Dang it!");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    } finally {
        if (didItWork) {
            /*Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Heck Yea!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Success");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();*/
        }
    }}
```

My PortfolioDatabase java:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "cointype_name";
public static final String KEY_QUANTITY = "cointype_quantity";
public static final String KEY_OUNCES = "cointype_ounces";
public static final String KEY_VALUE = "cointype_value";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PortfolioDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "cointypeTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_QUANTITY  + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_OUNCES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_VALUE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );  
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }       
}

public PortfolioDatabase(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public PortfolioDatabase open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();      
    return this;
}
 public void close(){
     ourHelper.close();

 }

public long createEntry(String coin, String quantity, String ounces, String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, coin);
    cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY, quantity);
    cv.put(KEY_OUNCES, ounces);
    cv.put(KEY_VALUE, value);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
    int iOunces = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OUNCES);
    int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/ c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iQuantity) + " " + c.getString(iOunces) + " " + c.getString(iValue) + "\n";
    }
    c.close();

    return result;
}

public String getCoin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
    int iOunces = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OUNCES);
    int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/ c.getString(iName).substring(0, Math.min(18, c.getString(iName).length())) + "\n";
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}

    public String getQty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
        int iOunces = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OUNCES);
        int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/ c.getString(iQuantity) + "\n";
        }           
    c.close();
    return result;
}

    public String getOunces() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
        int iOunces = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OUNCES);
        int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/  c.getString(iOunces) + "\n";
        }
        c.close();
        return result;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
        int iOunces = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OUNCES);
        int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/ c.getString(iValue) + "\n";
        }           
        c.close();
    return result;
}



public String getSingleValue(String aCoin) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE};     
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + aCoin, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
    int iOunces = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OUNCES);
    int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        result= c.getString(0);
        return result;
    }
    c.close();
    return null;
}

public String getHotness(long l) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_VALUE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String hotness = c.getString(2);
        return hotness;
    }
            c.close();
    return null;
}

//public void updateEntry(String mCoin, String mQuantity, String mValue) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
//  cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mCoin);
//  cvUpdate.put(KEY_QUANTITY, mQuantity);
//  cvUpdate.put(KEY_VALUE, mValue);
//  ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=" + mCoin, null); 
//}

public void updateEntry(String mCoin, String mQuantity, String mOunces, String mValue) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { mCoin };
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mCoin);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_QUANTITY, mQuantity);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_OUNCES, mOunces);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_VALUE, mValue);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=?", whereArgs);   
}

public void changeCurrency(String mCoin, String mValue) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { mCoin };
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mCoin);      
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_VALUE, mValue);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=?", whereArgs);   
}

//public void deleteEntry(String coin) throws SQLException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + coin, null);
//}

public void deleteEntry(String coin) throws SQLException{
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { coin };
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=?", whereArgs);
}

public void removeAll()
{
    /*// db.delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
    // If whereClause is null, it will delete all rows.
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS, null, null);
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS_GROUP, null, null);*/
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);

}
```

Logcat:

```
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.example.portfolio/databases/PortfolioDatabase, table = cointypeTable, query = SELECT _id, cointype_name, cointype_quantity, cointype_ounces, cointype_value FROM cointypeTable
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at com.example.portfolio.PortfolioDatabase.getData(PortfolioDatabase.java:79)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at com.example.portfolio.Portfolio.fillcoinstoadd(Portfolio.java:1472)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at com.example.portfolio.Portfolio$9.onClick(Portfolio.java:575)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)     08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-29 04:20:45.583: E/Cursor(1899):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 04:20:48.413: W/KeyCharacterMap(1899): No keyboard for id 0
```

Comment: Paste this line number code - PortfolioDatabase.java:79

Comment: @ChiragRaval Here is line 79:  Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: you have to close database also after complete your task

Comment: @ChiragRaval My database is closed too.  Here is my code to close it:  info.open();
   String data = info.getData();
        String ccoin = info.getCoin();
        String cqty = info.getQty();
        String counces = info.getOunces();
        String cvalue = info.getValue();
        info.close();

Comment: in your getData MEthod it not closed . ourDatabase

Comment: How do i properly code that i just added:  c.close();
  ourDatabase.close();
  return result; and the emulator forced closed.  I other methods similar to getDATA that run on Oncreate and are called throughout runtime.  How do i close database without getting force close?

Comment: Keep only one object of the database through activity and open it whenever required and close after complete it task . When you want to data or insert data in another function that time again open database and close it after complete your task . Same for Cursor.

Comment: @ChiragRaval Please. check my edit.  I've made all your suggested changes and still get error.

Answer (score 0):

To Overcome this problem close the cursor in getData Method() before return result.

```
c.close()
return result;
```

Comment: I've added c.close() before return result and still no luck

Comment: @Mr.Bojangles Close also Database after getting desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor in `getHotness()` is never closed.

As a general note, you should also make sure that cursors are closed even when exceptions are thrown. This means placing the `close()` call inside a `finally` block, like this:

```java
Cursor c = ...
try {
    // use the cursor
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: I've closed getHotness() and still no luck

Comment: I'm still getting the IllegalArgumentexception but the logcat isn't showing any errors. this is just weird.